# Show wrapperClass to visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, wrapper-class

Good day everyone,

I have created a wrapper class which is something like this:

```
public class wrapperClass {
        public Map<String,List<String>> selectedDefinitionList{get;set;}
        public Boolean isSelect{get;set;}
        public wrapperClass(Map<String,List<String>> selectedDefinitionList, boolean isSelect ) {
            this.selectedDefinitionList = selectedDefinitionList;
            this.isSelect = isSelect;
        }
    }
```

The purpose of this wrapper class is to combine the value of a map and a checkbox. At the moment I've tried to view the data of my wrapper and it is working as expected, but my problem is that how will i show the data of my wrapper specifically the map in it to my visual force page(pageblockTable). I've made something like this :

```
<apex:pageBlock > 
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AllObjectFieldMap}" var="field" styleClass="table table-striped">
<apex:column value="{!field.selectedDefinitionList}" headerValue="Salesforce Field"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

But I cannot see those data inside my map. I think I am lacking something. Please help thank you...

Comment: did you got solution.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma Sorry a late reply. Actually I've find a way to fix this problem. But thank you for helping. I've vote up your answer.thank you.

Comment: glad to know you find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

for display data from map you need to use dynamic binding. First need to get the key then fetch the record and iterate. you can read this [blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2011/03/visualforce-dynamic-map-bindings.html). something like this

```
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountsMap[selectedKey]}" var="acc">
                   <apex:column value="{!acc.name}"/>
                   <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingStreet}"/>
                   <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingCity}"/>
                   <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingPostalCode}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be used as an example to use Maps inside a visualforce page.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MyMap}" var="M">  
 <apex:repeat value="{!MyMap[M]}" var="temp">  
  <apex:column value="{!temp.Test_Curr__c}" />  
 </apex:repeat>  
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```